# Programmatically Set & Get browser Window Coordinate Values (x,y) in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I know how to do this using javascript when I'm doing a postback with this: `window.scrollTo(x, y);`. But I have a new scenario where I have to return to an exact scroll position a page (page1.aspx) from another page (page2.aspx). I want to be able to get the scroll position of page 1 and store it in a query string of the url for page2 so I can use it to set the scroll position when returning to page1.

I choose to do it in c# as javascript would probably not handle the cross page navigation nicely. I could be wrong though, but I need some help with this. Someone help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in javascript.  Just store the value in local storage and clear it when used.

```
 loadSetting = function (key, value) {
    value = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    return value;
}

saveSetting = function (key, value, bAuto) {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}

clearSetting = function (key) {
    window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I already took a different/better approach and I got what I wanted.